# How to render two different error pages for same error code (e.g. 404) in a single rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one rails application in which I have two sections, so I want to use two different layouts for the Error page.

For example, if an error is coming from Section 1 then layout1 / different page should be used for the Error (404, 500).

If error is coming from Section 2 then layout2 / different page should be used for the Error (404, 500).

I've written code to define the Error page, enabled with erb and ruby code.

in application.rb

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

in routes.rb

```
match "/404", :to => "errors#error_404"
match "/500", :to => "errors#error_500"
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. Hopefully it helps to solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Thought about it a little. If you only have a few types of errors, how about doing it like this?

In your `routes.rb`, at the very **last line**, add a

`match '/my_segment/*path', :to => 'errors#not_found'`

This should match any path that is not defined (which normally throws `ActionController::RoutingError`) and push it to your global error page.

You can play with play with the segments wildcard above to get your correct path. This should NOT affect your predefined paths, like `mydomain.com/controller1`.

Below is a more fine grained method of control.

This will help you match any errors from `mydomain.com/some_controller/bad_params`

```
def firstController < ApplicationController 
  def method_in_first_controller
    # Do something here
    rescue
      @error = # Error object here
      render :template=>"some_error_template", :status => :not_found # In specific action
  end
end


def secondController < ApplicationController 
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :rescue_not_found # In secondController

  def method_in_second_controller 
    # Do something  
  end

  protected
  def rescue_not_found
    @error = # Error object here
    render :template => 'some_error_template', :status => :not_found
  end

end

def ApplicationController 
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :rescue_not_found # Globally

  protected
  def rescue_not_found
    @error = # Error object here
    render :template => 'application/not_found', :status => :not_found
  end
end
```

Using referrer doesn't seem to get anywhere, sorry for the bad answer yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

In your errors controller you can have a check who is the referrer and have a conditional layout based on that

Comment: how can I check the referrer ? Is there any specific code for this?